# Does ArrayList.clear() nullify all objects inside recurcively?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I have such a class:

```
class C
{
   int a, b;
   ArrayList<int> c = new ArrayList();
};
```

and such a collection:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<C>> MyList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<C>>();
```

Would calling MyList.clear() nullify all the references to every ArrayList in the MyList and any additional objects inside of the each ArrayList in MyList? So, more precisely, will all elements inside class C.c be nullified as well as C.a and C.b?

Comment: See this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798424/what-is-the-garbage-collector-in-java

Comment: Java, simply put, automates the pointer process for you. It creates a variable in memory, points to it, breaks that pointer when you tell it to, and then the garbage collector notices there isn't a reference to it and eats it. So when you clear an array you are just breaking all of your pointers to space in memory. They are still there until they get garbage collected, but there is nothing pointing to them. At least this is my understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but if nothing else has reference to them, they *will* be eligible for garbage collection.

E.g., simpler example:

```
class Foo {
    Date dt;

    Foo() {
        this.dt = new Date();
    }
}

ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
list.add(new Foo());
list.clear();
```

As of the `clear`, the `Foo` object's `dt` has not been "nulled" or anything, but the `Foo` object and the things only it refers to (the `Date` inside it, in this case) are eligible for garbage collection.

Whereas:

```
class Foo {
    Date dt;

    Foo() {
        dt = new Date();
    }
}

ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
Foo f = new Foo();
list.add(f);
list.clear();
```

Here, the `Foo` object *isn't* eligible for garbage collection, because `f` still refers to it even though the list doesn't. Of course, if `f` is a local variable in a method, then as soon as the method returns, `f` goes out of scope — at which point, if nothing else has a reference to the object, it's eligible for GC. But that's beside the point, the point is that when the `clear` completes, the object is still referenced (by `f`).

Comment: hmm, regarding your second example, if f was a local variable, then after leaving the local space it wouldn't refer to the object anymore? And then it would be eligible to garbage collection?

Comment: @Savail: Yes, once `f` goes out of scope, if nothing else has a reference to that `Foo` object, the object becomes eligible for GC.

Answer (score 3):

If `c` is the only object that contains strong references to the contained lists then eventually they'll be garbage collected.

They won't be directly emptied though, just removed from the containing list. For example

```
ArrayList<C> inner = new ArrayList<C>();
inner.add(new C());

ArrayList<ArrayList<C>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<C>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<C>> outer2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<C>();

outer.add(inner);
outer2.add(inner);

outer.clear();
```

In this situation `inner` will be removed from `outer` but not from `inner2`, and since there will be another strong reference to `inner`, it's not eligible for garbage collection. Otherwise it will be released evenually, but all at once, not by emptying the inner elements.