# Does Kotlin have a garbage collector? If so, on which algorithm is it based?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, kotlin, garbage

I'm doing a school project on Kotlin and need to know how it deals with garbage.
Is it similar to Java in its garbage collector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the garbage collector in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798424/what-is-the-garbage-collector-in-java)

Comment: It's not a duplicate till you explain that they have the same garbage collector.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Kotlin is run in JVM so it uses the same garbage collector as Java or any other JVM based language.

Answer (score 9):

The garbage collector depends on the settings of your JVM runtime, not the language the program is written in (Jave, Kotlin, Groovy, Scala, Ceylon, etc)