# Use of pointers in Java

Tags: java, c++, pointers

For someone coming from C++ background, what is the best way to understand how Java operates without pointers?

Comment: Why do you think the absence of pointers needs to be compensated for?

Comment: Java has now way to acess memory directly _by design_ and the absence of pointers is considered a _feature_. You don't have to think about deleting stuff after using it, you can't (normally) create a segfault or forget to terminate a string etc etc...

Comment: *References* are essentially pointers. The only thing java disallows is free manipulation of their value; by restricting the possible operations to dereferencing and assignment.

Comment: @JamesKPolk in order to access memory. Am I wrong in expecting so?

Comment: You haven't defined what you mean by "access memory."  Java can manipulate objects on its heap as much as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Java is a garbage collected language. There are pointers, but they are managed for you by a memory manager. See various answers on SO, such as [What is the garbage collector in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798424/what-is-the-garbage-collector-in-java)