# Clojure GC mark&sweep (based on JVM)

Tags: clojure, garbage-collection, jvm

I was trying to understand Clojure's garbage collection system. Of course, its all about JVM and its GC. I understood it was parallel mark&sweep, but I couldn't understand how it work. Can someone explain it please?
In addition, I saw some talking about static and dynamic GC. Whats the difference? and what JVM uses?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the garbage collector in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798424/what-is-the-garbage-collector-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Clojure doesn't implement its own Garbage Collector - it runs on JVM as any other JVM byte code and thus uses whatever garbage collector implementation that is run by the JVM (based on defaults or command line parameters configuration).

Comment: I know that, but what GC the JVM uses?

Answer (score 0):

Better just to look up Java GC details, here's a page that might help: [Understanding Java Garbage Collection](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/understanding-java-garbage-collection).