# Does not using a return variable cause memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks

Does not storing or using what "sum" returns potentially cause a memory leak?

```
public int sum(int a, int b){
    System.out.println("total is: "+(a+b));
    return a+b;
}

sum(2,3);
```

Comment: No. The return value will not be stored in any variable. Hence, no memory is allocated for it.

Comment: You could clarify a bit, why are you asking this? Java has garbage collection, so only way to leak memory is to leave static (or otherwise long-lived) variables (often in containers) pointing to allocated objects, so they can't be freed even though they are not used ever again.

Comment: Further, this function returns primitive type, which won't have any allocation which needs to be freed. What kind of memory leak are you worried about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.  As it is a primitive value, it lives on the stack, and no heap memory is allocated for it.

But let's suppose, for the sake of demonstration, you are returning an object and not a primitive value (ex. `return new Integer(a+b)`).  There would still be no memory leak, as the object being returned would have no references to it, and thus would be subject to garbage collection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Going by your second part, if I were to return an Int Object, as in "return new Integer(a+b);" and store the result as "Integer res = sum(2,3);" and never use "res". Would this be subject to memory leaks?

Comment: If `res` is never used, then it will become subject to garbage collection when it goes out of scope.

Comment: what will happen to the return  if i simply use  "sum(2,4)"  ?

Answer (score -1):

No, Java has the garbage collector to help manage the memory.
Hope this could help. [What is the garbage collector in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798424/what-is-the-garbage-collector-in-java)