# we have to free up the memory while deleting a node in a linked list in c but we do not have to do the same in java,Why?

Tags: java, oop, linked-list

in case of c we have to do free(data) while deleting a node to free up the memory space occupied by the node manually but in case of java we do not have to do the same.Why and what happens??

Comment: That's due to the fact that [Java uses a garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798424/what-is-the-garbage-collector-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Java is a garbage collected language. This means freeing of these references is taken care of for you by the language itself. There are other forms of leaks, but for cases where the references to this node are no more, the memory is reclaimed on the next garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

when you remove the reference to the node will be eligible for the GC to free the memory
, For more information, you can read [Java Garbage collection basic Oracle doc](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)